# Passing Boost uBLAS matrices to OpenGL shader

Tags: opengl, boost, matrix, shader, ublas

I'm writing an OpenGL program where I compute my own matrices and pass them to shaders.  I want to use Boost's uBLAS library for the matrices, but I have little idea how to get a uBLAS matrix into OpenGL's shader uniform functions.

```
matrix<GLfloat, column_major> projection(4, 4);
// Fill matrix
...

GLuint projectionU = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionU, 1, 0, (GLfloat *)... Um ...);
```

Trying to cast the matrix to a GLfloat pointer causes an invalid cast error on compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should do it:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionU, 1, GL_FALSE, &projection.data()[0]);
```